# Why /lib/modules taking so much space on xubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I have a 2G home partition, /lib/modules is taking more that 1.5G.  I got 12 directory named after version of kernel 2.6.32 each taking 119k.  Why do I have all of that?   Do I need all of that?  If not, what is the clean way to remove what I don't need?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to remove/hide old kernel versions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/is-there-a-way-to-remove-hide-old-kernel-versions)

Comment: The other question do not mention anything about disk space.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Automatic update is installing each new kernel, but there is no clean-up, and there is a copy of the module for each kernel.

There is a package entry called :

linux-image-<version>-generic

Removing it removed the corresponding files in /lib/modules

Comment: This is correct, but there are more complete instructions for cleanup at http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-to-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove` does this for you in current Ubuntu versions. No need to manually clean the files.

Comment: Autoremove does not work for me. But `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.15.0-45-generic` does.

Comment: Is this safe to do ? What am i looking in here ? What are those packages ?

Comment: somehow ubuntu can't remove `/lib/modules/` dirs, even with `purge`. I receive the error `rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/modules/5.15.0-88-generic': Directory not empty`